# Get the sum of a column with two values in their cells (jquery datatables)

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I have a table running on [jquery datatables](https://datatables.net/), with a column that have cells with two values. I've already checked the examples of the docs - column().footer() and footerCallback, trying to get the sum of both values of the column and get the result displayed at the footer. But i can't get it to work when the cells have two values. I spent two days trying to get the sum at the footer, but with no positive results :(.

Example:

**Per day**

200 / 400

100 / 1200

700 / 300

**1000 / 1900 (total)**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var tableDataSet = [
     { 
     "name" : "John",
     "first_value" : "1200",
      "second_value" : "2000"
      },
   { 
     "name" : "Peter",
     "first_value" : "800",
      "second_value" : "3200"
      },
   { 
     "name" : "Tom",
     "first_value" : "500",
      "second_value" : "1400"
      }];

   $('#example').dataTable({
       "data": tableDataSet,
    "columns": [
         { "data": "name" },
         { "data": "null",
           "type": "natural",
        render:
         function(data, type, full) {
         return '<p><span class="first_value">'+ full.first_value +'</span> / <span class="second-value">' + full.second_value + '</span></p>';
      }
     }
        ],
     "paging":   false,
     "info":     false,
     "searching":false,
 initComplete: function () {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable();
            var totalFirst = 0;
            var totalSecond = 0;
            $.each(tableDataSet , function (i, l) {
                totalFirst += parseInt(tableDataSet [i]["first_value"]);
                totalSecond += parseInt(tableDataSet [i]["second_value"]);
            });

            table.row.add([totalFirst + "/" + totalSecond]).draw();
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/sorting/natural.js"></script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Per day</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Total:</th>
      <th>(SUMS of both values)</th>
 </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with something like this all you really need to do flesh out your custom renderer and hook into the drawCallback options.  Here is a fully working example that makes full use of the DataTables API:  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3s6mmou/21/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tableDataSet = [{
    "name": "John",
    "first_value": "1200",
    "second_value": "2000"
  }, {
    "name": "Peter",
    "first_value": "800",
    "second_value": "3200"
  }, {
    "name": "Tom",
    "first_value": "500",
    "second_value": "1400"
  }];

  $('#example').dataTable({
    "data": tableDataSet,
    "columns": [{
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "null",
      "type": "natural",
      "className": "per_day"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": [1],
      "render": function(data, type, full) {
        // We only want return HTML for display
        if (type === 'display') {
          return '<p><span class="first_value">' + full.first_value + '</span> / <span class="second-value">' + full.second_value + '</span></p>';
        }

        // Custom return for sorting.
        if (type === 'sort') {
          return full.first_value;
        }

        // Convert the values to numbers if we can otherwise set them to 0.
        var structuredData = {
          first_value: isNaN(full.first_value) ? 0 : +full.first_value,
          second_value: isNaN(full.second_value) ? 0 : +full.second_value
        }

        // Not dislay lets return our structured data
        return structuredData;
      }
    }],
    "paging": false,
    "info": false,
    "searching": false,
    "drawCallback": function(settings) {
      var jqDataTableObj = $(this);
      var apiDataTableObj = jqDataTableObj.DataTable();
      var totalFirst = 0;
      var totalSecond = 0;
      var sumColumnIndex = -1;

      $(apiDataTableObj.cells(".per_day").nodes()).each(function() {
        var cell = apiDataTableObj.cell(this);

        // We want that nice object we built in the render function.  So don't use
        // "display" or "sort" for this function.
        let structuredCellData = cell.render("filter");
        totalFirst += structuredCellData.first_value;
        totalSecond += structuredCellData.second_value;

        // See if we grabbed a reference to the column index
        if (sumColumnIndex === -1) {
          // Get the column index.
          sumColumnIndex = cell.index().column;
        }
      });

      var footerNode = apiDataTableObj.column(sumColumnIndex).footer();
      $(footerNode).html(totalFirst + " / " + totalSecond);
    }
  });
});
```

I brought over the javascript portion.  Visit the JSFiddle link to see it in action.  Make sure you checkout the updates to the "columns", "columnDefs", and "drawCallback" options in that JSFiddle.

Also the solution I have here will work regardless of how you get the data into the DataTable. If you implement serverside paging then the SUM will only be for the visible page.

EDIT:
Changed the "render" function to return the first value as a number when sorting.  This will allow the library sorting functions to sort it properly.

To add another column like the per day one just add an additional column def for this new column and modify the "drawCallback" function to sum values for this new column as well.  If you are just doing the same thing (column summation) the code above can be used as an example for additional similar columns.

If you have specific questions on how this code works let me know and we can move the discussion to a chat.

Comment: Uppps. I just noticed that the column "Per day" doesn't have sort capabilities anymore.

Comment: @Fedegiro we can reimplement that using the renderer.  How you like it sorted since you have two values in there.?

Comment: sorted by the first value (first_value). By the way, what if i add another column like "Per day", say "Per month"?

Comment: @Fedegiro sorry things got crazy at work and I forgot about you.  I will try and update my answer this week with the sorting.

Comment: @Fedegiro  Sorry about the late reply I updated the above to allow it to be sorted by the first value.  Look at the changes in the "renderer" function so that it returns the first value as a number so that it can be properly sorted.

Comment: Nice function! But I've got a problem, it'll always sum all data, I need to sum after the table has been filtered. No idea where to start, any advise highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try add this below of `"searching":false,` it will run after table complete draw.

```
"initComplete": function () {
                var table = $('#example').DataTable();
                var totalFirst = 0;
                var totalSecond = 0;
                $.each(tableDataSet , function (i, l) {
                    totalFirst += parseInt(tableDataSet [i]["first_value"]);
                    totalSecond += parseInt(tableDataSet [i]["second_value"]);
                });

                table.row.add({
                    "name": "<b>Totals</b>",
                    "first_value": totalFirst,
                    "second_value": totalSecond
                }).draw();
            }
```

Hi, I updated the answer. Can you test this.

Comment: I just added that piece of code, but i get "undefined" for both values. BTW, I need to display the sums in the table's footer (tfoot). 

I added one column for "Name" data (and now i get "Requested unknown parameter 'name' for row 3"). The word "Total" must be under the first column, and the sums under the second column.

Comment: thank you saf21! what if i have ajax sourced data instead of JS sourced data ("var tableDataSet")? Ex:

$('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": '../ajax/data/arrays.txt' 
});